# C# MVC System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper error

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to C#. And I encountered such an error that I couldn't solve.

I have a class called Colons. And I do all my work in this class. I send this class to the View side. However, when I define the View as a model and return it with foreach, I get an error.And on the controller side, I call this colons class in the GetColumn action.

**My "Create Table" controller**

```
namespace PDF.Controllers
{
public class TabloOlusturController : Controller
{
    DBKatalogEntities db = new DBKatalogEntities();
    // GET: TabloOlustur
    
    public ActionResult Index()
     {
        List<SelectListItem> KolonTuru = (from i in db.Kolonlar.ToList()
                                          select new SelectListItem
                                          {
                                              Text = i.KolonTuru,
                                              Value = i.ID.ToString()
                                          }).ToList();
        ViewBag.KolonTuru = KolonTuru;
        //ViewBag.Kolon = c.Kolons.ToList();
        return View(GetKolon());
    }
    public ActionResult AddKolon(string KolonTuru, string KolonAdi)
    {
        if (KolonAdi != string.Empty)
        {
            if (KolonTuru != "Veri Tipi Seçiniz")
            {
                var kolon = db.Kolonlar.Where(x => x.KolonTuru == KolonTuru).FirstOrDefault();
                kolon.KolonAdi = KolonAdi;
                if (kolon != null)
                {
                    GetKolon().AddColon(kolon);
                }
                return Json("Basarili");
            }
            else
            {
                return Json("Bos");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("Hata");
        }
    }
    public ActionResult DeleteKolon(string Kolonadi)
    {
        //var kolon = db.Kolonlar.Where(x => x.ID == ID).FirstOrDefault();
        var kolon = GetKolon().Kolons.Where(x => x.Kolonlar.KolonAdi == Kolonadi).FirstOrDefault();
        if (kolon != null)
        {
            GetKolon().DeleteColon(kolon);
        }
        return Json("Basarili");
    }
    public Colons GetKolon()
    {
        var Kolon = Session["Kolons"];
        if (Kolon == null)
        {
            Kolon = new Colons();
            Session["Kolons"] = Kolon;

        }
        return (Colons)Kolon;
    }
}
```

}

**This is my view**

```
@using PDF.Models
@model Colons
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

When I go to the index action with a breakpoint in the controller, it comes to the View and gives an error in the layout.

"System.Web.HttpException: Error executing subrequest for handler ''System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.'"

InvalidOperationException: This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.

This is my Colons class

```
public class Colons
    {
        private List<Sutun> _kolonlar = new List<Sutun>();
        public List<Sutun> Kolons
        {
            get { return _kolonlar; }
            
        }

        public void AddColon(Kolonlar kolon)
        {
            _kolonlar.Add(new Sutun() { Kolonlar = kolon });
        }
        //public void DeleteColon(Kolonlar kolon)
        //{
        //    _kolonlar.RemoveAll(x => x.Kolonlar.KolonAdi == kolon.KolonAdi);
        //}
        public void ClearColon()
        {
            _kolonlar.Clear();
        }

        public void DeleteColon(Sutun kolon)
        {
            _kolonlar.RemoveAll(x => x.Kolonlar.KolonAdi == kolon.Kolonlar.KolonAdi);
        }
    }

    public class Sutun
    {
        public Kolonlar Kolonlar { get; set; }

        //public int ID { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set The **JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet** parameter in your Json Response.

Example :

```
public ActionResult DeleteKolon(string Kolonadi)
{
    //var kolon = db.Kolonlar.Where(x => x.ID == ID).FirstOrDefault();
    var kolon = GetKolon().Kolons.Where(x => x.Kolonlar.KolonAdi == Kolonadi).FirstOrDefault();
    if (kolon != null)
    {
        GetKolon().DeleteColon(kolon);
    }
    return Json("Basarili", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Pass this parameter to all the **return Json** method.

Comment: I guess I told you wrong. Problem: It gives this error when opening the page.So it gives an error without doing anything.

Comment: Please Double-check that the GetKolon() model is being passed to the view correctly.  Debug that code Make sure that the model is being instantiated correctly and that all necessary properties are being assigned.